# Syntax error: end of file unexpected

Tags: command-line, scripts, compiling, jenkins

I have a shell script which is use to build a project on jenkins. 
When i run that script on my local windows machine it runs fine, But when i run that script on my Ubuntu server it gives an error

**Error:**

```
Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "}")
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

I am using Jenkins on both my windows local machine and my Ubuntu server

**Contents of Shell Script :**

```
echo 'asklytics-commons-test: cleaning ...'
./gradlew clean || { echo 'gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies FAILED!!' ; exit 1; }

echo 'asklytics-commons-test: building ...'
./gradlew build || { echo 'gradlew building FAILED!!' ; exit 1; }

echo 'asklytics-commons-test: jarring...'
./gradlew jar || { echo 'gradlew jarring FAILED!!' ; exit 1; }

echo 'asklytics-commons-test: publishing ...'
./gradlew publish || { echo 'gradlew publish FAILED!!' ; exit 1; }
```

Comment: Is this the whole script?

Comment: Yes, this is the whole script @heemayl

Comment: Since neither the `Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure` nor `Finished: FAILURE` errors are present in your script, nor AFAIK are internal shell errors, they are presumably coming from inside your `./gradlew` (gradle wrapper?) script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shebang line must be the very first thing in the file. Since you use bash features, the first line of the file must be

> #!/bin/bash or #!/usr/bin/env bash.

Comment: I had that added, but when executing shell it gave error "not found" and when i removed it it started giving me this error now